# What is the difference between the TensorFlow batch normalization implementations?

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

TensorFlow seems to implement at least 3 versions of batch normalization:

- [`tf.nn.batch_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/batch_normalization)
- [`tf.layers.batch_normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization)
- [`tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm)

These all have different arguments and documentation.

What is the difference between these, and which one should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are actually very different.

- `nn.batch_normalization` performs the basic operation (i.e. a simple normalization)
- `layers.batch_normalization` is a batchnorm "layer", i.e. it takes care of setting up the trainable parameters etc. At the end of the day, it is a wrapper around `nn.batch_normalization`. Chances are this is the one you want to use, unless you want to take care of setting up variables etc. yourself.

It's similar to the difference between `nn.conv2d` and `layers.conv2d`, for example.

As for the `contrib` version, I can't say for sure, but it seems to me like an experimental version with some extra parameters not available in the "regular" `layers` one.

Answer (score 1):

The are all based on the same paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167
So they should do the same thing.

Some functions move around the code but the old versions are kept to keep backwards compatibility and you end up with more than one version.

I would recommend using the simplest one that lets you do your project (that is tf.nn.batch_normalization). If you need features/parameters that are not offered pick the one that works for you.

Note:
tf.contrib.* is not guarateed to remain backwards compatible (the api might change in a future version).